# PHP only allow server to access a PHP file

Tags: php, javascript

I have three pages:

```
index.html
getjavascript.php?id=index
index.js
```

index.html includes the script

```
'getjavascript.php?id=index'
```

and getjavascript dynamically gets the script index.js.

Is there any way to prevent external users from directly accessing

```
getjavascript.php
```

using PHP?

index.js is in a hidden location.

Thanks,

Comment: You should really clarify how each file is being "included" because it sounds like index.html has no SSI or anything thus there is no way to do what you want - but you should clarify your scenario more.

Comment: You hide a file only to have its contents exposed by another file?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that index.html contains an include similar to the snippet below (assumption is that we're doing a client-side pull of this javascript).

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="getjavascript.php?id=index" />
```

If your intent is to hide secrets within the javascript file, there is no way of stopping a user from retrieving the contents. They can trivially use developer tools to view the contents. Furthermore, because the browser needs to download the file, there's not really a way to distinguish between a user accessing directly versus a browser retrieving this file.

If your intent is to obfuscate the fact that your server is using PHP, you can use `mod_rewrite` to remove the extension.

Server side includes are a different story and modifications to `.htaccess` or moving this file outside of your webroot directory would work.

Comment: Hi, i'm more trying to hide the source of the index.js. What i was thinking was a if($_SERVER[webpage] == 'getjavascript.php'){ exit(); }else{ echo $file; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by using htaccess.

Redirect /getjavascript.php http://example.com/newdirectory/

Comment: This won't work since the browser needs to make requests to getjavascript.php?id=index and will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see two ways to solve your problem

1. Using Apache RewriteRule directive. This way will allow you to hide real URL name in your html file
2. Try to use additional parameter in getjavascript.php that detect that if this url called directly from browser (not from html form or link).

Answer (score -1):

Put the include script outside of the document root. For example, if you have your root in `public_html`, create a folder outside `public_html` to put your included files in. That way, your script can read them but random people on the internet can't.